# Opera 9 (Presto 2.12) CSS tag compatibility with keyframe animation

Tags: html, css, opera

I'm trying to create a rotation animation effect that would run within an old version of an embedded Opera browser (Presto 12.2) on a Tivo receiver. CSS Calls such as "rotateY" don't render at all on the browser so I had to use the scale transform property to create the spinning illusion, however I'm now stuck with trying to change the background image within a keyframe animation (halfway down the keyframe animation at 50%, I would change the background image to something else). Everything works perfectly fine within Chrome, but due to restrictions with browser I was wondering if there is a work around out there as I've scoured the interwebs for a while and couldn't find a solution to my problem? I'm not experienced with javascript/jquery so everything is purely within CSS. Thank you all.

Code:

HTML part:

```
<div style="position:absolute; TOP: 200px; LEFT: 200px" class ="scaling" ></div>
```

CSS part:

```
div {
  float: left;
  width: 61px;
  height: 68px;
  background-image: url('image1.gif');
  }


.scaling{
    float: left;
    animation-name: scale1;
    animation-duration:1s;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    animation-timing-function:steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes scale1{
            0%  {
                    transform:  scale(0.9, 1.0);

                }
            10% {
                    transform:  scale(0.7, 1.0);
                }
            20% {
                    transform:  scale(0.6, 1.0);
                } 
            30% {
                    transform:  scale(0.4, 1.0);
                }
            40% {
                    transform:  scale(0.2, 1.0);
                }
            50% {
                    transform:  scale(0.1, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                }
            60% {
                    transform:  scale(0.2, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                }
            70% {
                    transform:  scale(0.4, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                }
            80% {
                    transform:  scale(0.6, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                }
            90% {
                    transform:  scale(0.7, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                }
            100% {
                    transform:  scale(0.9, 1.0);
                    background-image: url('image2.gif');
                 }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resorted to using the scale- transform option to create the spinning effect that works on the target browser. One image will scale from 1.0, 1.0 to 0.025, 1.0 and the other one from 0.025, 1.0 to 1.0, 1.0.

```
@keyframes scaleBigToSmall{
    from {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
    to {transform: scale(0, 1.0);}
}                       

@keyframes scaleSmallToBig{
    from {transform: scale(0, 1.0);}
    to {transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);}
}
```